# how to import mysql database

Tags: mysql

I'm not a great expert in php and mysql. I want to test my drupal site, but I don't know how to import my local database to the webserver.

I only have ftp credential, database name and database credential.
phpmyadmin and any type of control panel are not present.

This is the ftp folders tree (I'm using filezilla):

- anon_ftp
- bin
- cgi_bin
- conf
- error_docs
- httpdocs
- httpsdocs
- pd
- private
- statistics
- subdomains
- web_users

I've published the drupal's folder in httpdocs folder.
May I publish my database dump file through ftp?

I ask you a little help before contacting my hosting provider

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you use your ftp credentials to gain access to the server via ssh (that's the command ssh in terminal window on mac/linux and putty on windows)? can you you use your local phpmyadmin to gain access to their database remotely?

Comment: I've already tried your suggestion using putty connecting to my domain address (with my ftp credential), but with no result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) (installation instructions [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#quick_install)) would be a valid way to do this. phpMyAdmin provides a convenient interface for importing database dumps.

Alternatively, [phpMiniAdmin](http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/) is a lightweight tool that fits in one small file.

Comment: but how would op do this, when it's not certain that op can access the server apart from via ftp?

Comment: @davo but what else does he need except FTP? Seeing as he wants to test a Drupal site, we can safely assume he has a web root, and http access

Comment: I will try phpMiniAdmin, it seems to be a good and simple solution. Thank you

Comment: I've tried phpMiniAdmin. Database succesfully imported. Now I have some Drupal error to resolve...

Answer (score 3):

Without having an interface like phpmyadmin this could be a hard task.  The only think I can think of is to use php to run a .sql script.

1. Export your database into a *.sql file
2. upload it to your webserver
3. In a php page, do commands to connect to your database, and then run a command like

this:

```
mysql_query("SOURCE path/to/sqlfile.sql");
```

Then hit that php page with your web browser

reference: [php mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: This works only if the mySQL user is allowed to use the `SOURCE` command, though.

Comment: @pekka Good to know!  I just assumed since he said that he had the database credential that he had permissions.